# create array of size N before compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, initialization

I am trying to create the array `new_array` of size `max_value` inside function `something`. The value of `max_value` can only be known at runtime. How can I fix this code?

```
void something (int input_array[], int array_length) {
    int max_value = *std::max_element(input_array, input_array + 8);
    int new_array[max_value] = {0};
}
```

I am getting the live issue message: "variable sized object may not be initialized"

Comment: C++ does not have variable length arrays.  Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Use `std::vector<int> new_array(max_value);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: "before compile time" is just *too* early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ doesn't have variable length arrays (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1887178/312896) why) though [some compilers may support them](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) (and yours as well).

If you are ok with using heap instead of stack you could use std::vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> new_array(max_value, 0);
```

But to remove the error you can just remove initializer and initialize array manually like this:

```
int new_array[max_value];
memset( new_array, 0, max_value*sizeof(int) );
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<int> new_array(max_value,0);` in order to initialize all values of the array to zero.